# 'Const declarations are not supported in strict mode' syntax error

Tags: javascript, ios, ecmascript-6, safari, constants

I came across this `SyntaxError` in other questions and I'm curious about it:

> Unexpected keyword 'const'. Const declarations are not supported in strict mode

To my understanding, it may happen in some Safari/Mobile Safari versions and related environments like iOS web view (React Native, etc).

There's a lot of related questions but they usually suggest a way to fix the problem (e.g. change Babel configuration) without explaining its origins.

The error doesn't make much sense. Usually it's strict mode where ES6 features are allowed in environments where they are partially supported.

Under which conditions can this error appear?

Is it specific to some Safari/iOS versions?

Does it mean that `const` keyword will work in sloppy mode but won't work in strict mode (`use strict`)?

*The question doesn't address any specific code problem. It's about the circumstances under which the error can appear.*

Comment: Old bug and is fixed in any major browser out there: https://caniuse.com/#feat=const -> _3) Only recognized when NOT in strict mode_